# Routing Error - rescue Layout + No route matches [GET] "/sockjs-node/info"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting a Route Error in my Rails 5 app and to render or redirect page takes several seconds.

- ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/sockjs-node/info")
- 5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [37 times] (506.0ms)
- 5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (17531.2ms)

**Log:**

```
Started GET "/sockjs-node/info?t=1473196651723" for ::1 at 2016-09-06 22:17:31 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/sockjs-node/info"):

actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
  Rendering /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendered collection of /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [37 times] (506.0ms)
  Rendering /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendering /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/Dudis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (17531.2ms)
```

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'menu#home'   get 'menus/pricing' => 'menu#pricing', path: 'pricing'   get 'menus/features'=> 'menu#features', path: 'features'
  get 'dashboards/index'
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'}
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
  resources :users
  resources :checkers, only: [:new, :create, :show]   resources :newsletters, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

**Rake routes:**

```
                               Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                  Controller#Action
                     dashboards_index GET      /dashboards/index(.:format)                  dashboards#index
                     new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)                     devise/sessions#new
                         user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)                     devise/sessions#create
                 destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                    devise/sessions#destroy
     user_facebook_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/facebook(.:format)               users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
      user_facebook_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/facebook/callback(.:format)      users/omniauth_callbacks#facebook
user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/google_oauth2(.:format)          users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
 user_google_oauth2_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/google_oauth2/callback(.:format) users/omniauth_callbacks#google_oauth2
                        user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)                    devise/passwords#create
                    new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)                devise/passwords#new
                   edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)               devise/passwords#edit
                                      PATCH    /users/password(.:format)                    devise/passwords#update
                                      PUT      /users/password(.:format)                    devise/passwords#update
             cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                      devise/registrations#cancel
                    user_registration POST     /users(.:format)                             devise/registrations#create
                new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)                     devise/registrations#new
               edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                        devise/registrations#edit
                                      PATCH    /users(.:format)                             devise/registrations#update
                                      PUT      /users(.:format)                             devise/registrations#update
                                      DELETE   /users(.:format)                             devise/registrations#destroy
                                               /cable                                       #<ActionCable::Server::Base:0x007ff348689c80 @mutex=#<Monitor:0x007ff348689c58 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007ff348689c08>>, @pubsub=nil, @worker_pool=nil, @event_loop=nil, @remote_connections=nil>
                                 root GET      /                                            menu#home
                        menus_pricing GET      /pricing(.:format)                           menu#pricing
                       menus_features GET      /features(.:format)                          menu#features
                                users GET      /users(.:format)                             users#index
                                      POST     /users(.:format)                             users#create
                             new_user GET      /users/new(.:format)                         users#new
                            edit_user GET      /users/:id/edit(.:format)                    users#edit
                                 user GET      /users/:id(.:format)                         users#show
                                      PATCH    /users/:id(.:format)                         users#update
                                      PUT      /users/:id(.:format)                         users#update
                                      DELETE   /users/:id(.:format)                         users#destroy
                             checkers POST     /checkers(.:format)                          checkers#create
                          new_checker GET      /checkers/new(.:format)                      checkers#new
                              checker GET      /checkers/:id(.:format)                      checkers#show
                          newsletters POST     /newsletters(.:format)                       newsletters#create
                       new_newsletter GET      /newsletters/new(.:format)                   newsletters#new
```

How I could debug it and what is sockjs-node/info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently ran into this as well. It started after I built a rails5 api on localhost:3000.

After I started working on another unrelated project that used localhost:3000, I started getting this error.

To remedy I just specified another port for the time being `rails server -p 8000`

Other than that, I haven't figured out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`sockjs-node` is used by `webpack-dev-server`.

To avoid the routing error, be sure the port used by Webpack is different than the port used by Puma, the Rails server used by default. Assets will still be available even on different ports.

For `webpack-dev-server`, check `config/webpacker.yml` :

```rb
dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
```

If using the default `rails server`, check `config/puma.rb` :

```rb
# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests; default is 3000.
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
```